# Strange difficulty with DSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations

Consider:

```
sys = {u (1 - u + a v), r v (1 - v + b u)}

(* {u (1 - u + a v), r (1 + b u - v) v} *)
```

And:

```
sys1 = sys /. {a -> 2, b -> 3, r -> 1}

(* {u (1 - u + 2 v), (1 + 3 u - v) v} *)
```

Then I get this strange error:

```
sol[{u0_, v0_}] = 
 DSolveValue[{{u'[t], v'[t]} == sys1 /. {u -> u[t], v -> v[t]}, {u[0],
      v[0]} == {u0, v0}}, {u[t], v[t]}, t]
```

The error:

[image]

What is making me get u[t]'[t]? I did quit the kernel before running this code and submitting here.

Comment: Check out the value of `{u'[t], v'[t]} == sys1 /. {u -> u[t], v -> v[t]}`.  I believe you want `{u'[t], v'[t]} == (sys1 /. {u -> u[t], v -> v[t]})` -- note the parentheses.

Comment: It's a question of the precedence of `==` over `/.`

Comment: I just realized I tried that, but the system hung and I had to abort. Now I realize it is because of the nonlinear system and I have to use NDSolveValue. Thanks for the notice.